# Jaqwire KEB vs Shimano DA Brake Cables

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, product-rec, cable, cable-housing

Looking to replace my brake cables/outers on my CX bikes (105 brifters and TRP Spyres brakes). Both outers (front and rear) run the full length (shifter to brake) on my CAADX so there’s a lot of outer there (i.e. lots of potential for compression). Looks like I can get a decent price on some Jagwire KEB (road pro) cables/outers, but also heard that it’s hard to beat Shimano DA cables (and I can get those for even cheaper). Haven’t seen much about Shimano cables for disc brakes online but it seems like a good cable is a good cable. Has anyone tried/compared both? Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. Specific product recommendations are off-topic here. See *[What topics can I ask about here?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)* for more info.

Comment: A good cable functions better than a cheap cable.  I had to buy a $15 gear inner (which was $3 on Wiggle) for time reasons.  The expensive cable is half the weight and has a slippery outer coating.  It shifts incredibly well, worth the 5x cost difference.

Comment: If you completely re-wrote this question as "What are the differences between cheap and more costly brake cables?"  then this question would be less of a shopping comparison and more long-term useful.

Answer (score 1):

Only use compressionless brake housing on mechanical discs if you want them to perform well and avoid problems with bottoming the lever against the bar. Shimano brake housings, even Dura-Ace BC-9000 as far as I know, are all the conventional spiral design. I've put KEB-SL housing on many Spyres and other mechanicals and it works great.

Comment: Here, here... agreed.  Compressionless all the way!